# BlockUI - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'blockUI'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-blockui

I am trying to use the blockUI jQuery Plugin. I am including the libraries as such;

```
<script src="http://malsup.com/jquery/block/jquery.blockUI.1.33.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However Chrome is showing a `TypeError`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'blockUI'
```

I have tried `$.blockUI` and `$.fn.blockUI` without success!

Thanks

Edit:
I am calling the blockUI code from a function, which is triggered from a button click;

```
$(function () {
   $('#btnAddIssue').click(function(){
   $.blockUI();
 )};
)};
```

Answer (score 5):

change the order of scripts, because `jquery.blockUI.1.33.js` which depends on the `jquery.min.js`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.com/jquery/block/jquery.blockUI.1.33.js"></script>
```

---

You have syntax errors in your script,

```
$(function () {
   $('#btnAddIssue').click(function(){
   $.blockUI();
 )}; //--------------> Improper closing  change it })
)}; //----------------> Improper closing change it })
```

**Fixed:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnAddIssue').click(function () {
        $.blockUI();
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/VLt9R/1/)

Comment: Then you probably declare another script that uses BlockUI before it is declared. Hard to say with only two lines of code.

Comment: @TomSothcott I should have I have tried in jsfiddle and it is working http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/VLt9R/

Comment: See my edit, I am calling the blockUI from a button click event.

Comment: @TomSothcott are you using any other script libraries on that page which might steal jquery's `$`?

Comment: @TomSothcott that was a syntax error, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue, I had included the jQuery library twice.. oops :)